# Windows Mobile 6 / 6.5 performance monitoring

Tags: performance, windows-mobile, monitoring

I'm writing an app for a Pocket PC device which appears to be slowly leaking resources - after 24hrs the device slowly becomes unresponsive and eventually locks up altogether.

On XP/Vista I would at this point fire up trusty PerfMon and plot graphs of handles, threads,  memory, mutexes etc - anything that could be leaking.

Can someone recommend an approach for this on Windows Mobile? What would be ideal would be a mobile agent that collects performance counters and reports them back to a PC-based instance of PerfMon.

I have seen [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404355.aspx), but it appears to be specific to .NET compact framework - I still work in C++/win32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start out with [App Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D275348A-D937-4D88-AE25-28702C78748D&displaylang=en), but really the tool that I (and everyone I know) uses is [Entrek's Codesnitch](http://entrek.com/codesnitch.html).  That thing pays for itself in the first use, every time.

Answer (score 0):

Embedded Visual C++ 4 contained "Remote Performance Monitor" that could do just that. Microsoft retracted EVC4 as free download some time ago, but it can still be downloaded from MSDN or found on the internet. It does not appear to work with Windows Embedded 6 and newer though and I am not sure which kernel Windows Mobile 6 are built on.